# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration

Tags: spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am developing code **Spring Boot Microservices Project - Part 1 - Spring Boot Config Server & Eureka Service Discovery** from - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fq85GschdLw and getting the below error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfiguration.createSslConfiguration(VaultConfiguration.java:101)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration.<init>(org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration, org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration, java.util.List, java.util.List)'

The method's class, org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.0/spring-vault-core-2.3.0.jar!/org/springframework/vault/support/SslConfiguration.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration: file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.0/spring-vault-core-2.3.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration

[2m2021-04-13 20:13:32.155[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m20424[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfiguration.createSslConfiguration(VaultConfiguration.java:101)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration.<init>(org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration, org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration, java.util.List, java.util.List)'

The method's class, org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.0/spring-vault-core-2.3.0.jar!/org/springframework/vault/support/SslConfiguration.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration: file:/C:/Users/pc/.m2/repository/org/springframework/vault/spring-vault-core/2.3.0/spring-vault-core-2.3.0.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.programming.techie</groupId>
    <artifactId>order-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>order-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

spring.application.name=order-service
server.port=0
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${random.uuid}

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

# Vault
spring.cloud.vault.host=localhost
spring.cloud.vault.port=8200
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http
spring.cloud.vault.authentication=TOKEN
spring.cloud.vault.token=s.QjdrL9Y6oLhJssBFtOXtuNDc
spring.cloud.vault.application-name=order-service
```

Comment: Please check this issue, the possible resolution is to change the version spring-vault to 2.3.2

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/584

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the `SpringBoot` version from `2.4.4` to `2.3.10.RELEASE` and `<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR11</spring-cloud.version>`.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade the SpringBoot version from 2.4.4 to 2.4.2